# Why do we have different return types in the android repository

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, clean-architecture, kotlin-flow

I was reading the official android architecture app to learn more about the architecture pattern and I see that we are returning Flow while returning SomeOtherClass from the methods defined in the repository.

Here is the code: https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/data/TaskRepository.kt

```
package com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.data

import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

/**
 * Interface to the data layer.
 */
interface TaskRepository {

    fun getTasksStream(): Flow<List<Task>>

    suspend fun getTasks(forceUpdate: Boolean = false): List<Task>

    suspend fun refresh()

    fun getTaskStream(taskId: String): Flow<Task?>

    suspend fun getTask(taskId: String, forceUpdate: Boolean = false): Task?

    suspend fun refreshTask(taskId: String)

    suspend fun createTask(title: String, description: String): String

    suspend fun updateTask(taskId: String, title: String, description: String)

    suspend fun completeTask(taskId: String)

    suspend fun activateTask(taskId: String)

    suspend fun clearCompletedTasks()

    suspend fun deleteAllTasks()

    suspend fun deleteTask(taskId: String)
}
```

When building an app, what's the best way to decide when we need to return a flow vs an actual object from a repository? I also see that the flows are non-suspend functions while methods which returns the object are suspend functions. Why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing the below explanation with the assumption that this is a database-backed repository, but the same concepts apply if the repository is backed up by other sources, such as a web server.

Flows are cold--the object itself only defines what it will do when collected but doesn't actually do it yet. No database read has to be done to create the lightweight Flow object, so there's no reason for the function to suspend if it returns a Flow.

A Flow returned by Room monitors the database. When you start collecting it, it first emits the current value of the associated database query. Then it emits again every time the database is modified, because the result of the query might be different after the modification.

A suspend function for retrieving something in the database simply returns the result of making the query at the time you call it. You can also define suspend functions in the DAO for making changes to the database (e.g. inserting rows, deleting rows, or editing rows). It wouldn't make sense for these to return Flows. Flows return data, so they are only relevant to queries.

When you're defining a function to retrieve something, choosing between a Flow and suspend function comes down to how you will be using it in the UI layer.

The other option is to simply always return a Flow, and let callers decide if they only one to get the current value through a suspend function, which can be done by calling `.first()` on the flow.

Comment: There is some related information in this question I answered yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76030366/when-to-use-suspend-function-and-flow-together-or-seperate-in-kotlin/76031024#76031024

Comment: Does that mean that all the rest api network calls should never returning a flow?

Comment: Well, you could return a flow that repeats the request every so often to get updated data.

Comment: Just for the complete clarity of how to actually implement this, does it mean that we will always have a coroutine running in a IO Dispatcher along with delay statements(lets say 20 secs)and which emits the response we got from server request and we use that flow in UI layer? Do you know if this is how Room database handles the realtime update of tables?

Comment: Room doesn't use a loop with a timer. Every time you call a function that modifies the database, it notifies all the flows (or LiveDatas or RxObservables) that it has returned and are currently being collected so they will know to make a new query and emit the result. This is of course a lot more desirable than pre-emptively scanning the database repeatedly. But to do a timer, you would only need an IO dispatcher if calling blocking functions. If you have a suspending REST get request, you don't need to specify dispatcher. You could define your flow like....

Comment: `fun foo() = flow { while (true) { emit(getSomethingViaSuspendFunction()); delay(20_000L) } }`